# Rails4 - How to create and the best practices way to create list box for countries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, listbox

I have a user model with name and email.
Now I want to add country listbox during the user signup.
Right now I can list all users. I want to add country column to the model because I want to create a view later where users can search other users based on the country.

I am not using devise gem.

I know the steps to do but I don't know which is the correct way.
Should I store the countries in a database ?

First add column

```
rails generate migration add_country_to_users country:<what_type_?>
```

Then migrate

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Then add validations in model

```
app/models/user.rb
validates :country, inclusion: %w(full_list?)
```

Add list box in registration form

```
app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= f.label :country %>
<%= f.f.select :country %>
```

Add list box in update form

```
app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= f.label :country %>
<%= f.f.select :country %>
```

Add it in strong params

```
app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :country)
end
```

Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your concern/issue with the approach you've outlined?

Comment: @J0e3gan How do I store the country list? and How do i list them in the views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be store it in some .yml file, and store country code in database for specific user.

For example:

```
countries:
  us: United States
  ger: Germany
```

And you can load file in intializer,

```
CONFIG = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML.load(File.read(path_to_file)))`
```

**UPDATE**

or just use this gem https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select

Comment: Sorry. Could you please share where i should put "  us: United States, ger: Germany"? What should be put in .yml file and what in database? :( Sorry am a newbie. But if you can point to some resource, I will learn and understand.

Comment: You can just put it in `/config ` directory. You can save country code into database and get country name from yml file